# How do you change the text colour of a label programmatically in Microsoft Expression Blend 4

Tags: c#, expression, expression-blend

How do I change a label's colour (for example labelname = myLBL) programmatically?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehrm... how about:

```
myLBL.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: Ahha thats how you do it - yeah what i wanted was myLBL.Foreground = Brushes.Black;