# How do you change foreground color of a textBox in C# in Microsoft Expression Blend 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend-4, sketchflow

This is my first time working with Microfoft Expression Blend. My project is Silverlight Prototype(sketchflow).
I have a TextBox(TextBox = logUser) and I want to change it's Foreground color.

I tried `logUser.Foreground = Brushes.Black` which I read in a different post([How do you change the text colour of a label programmatically in Microsoft Expression Blend 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712938/how-do-you-change-the-text-colour-of-a-label-programmatically-in-microsoft-expre)), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Black is the default foreground. So be sure to change it before you use `logUser.Foreground = Brushes.Black`. Otherwise, there will be no change. I know you are not that careless, but still, just saying... in case it **is** the case..

Comment: The problem is that build fails. @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ

Comment: Can you share what exact error you are getting when you are building

Comment: The name 'Brushes' does not exist in the current context. @Malcolm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight does not have a Brushes class , hence it throws you an error .

I went through the defination of System.Windows.Media and got to know that it provides you a **SolidColorBrush** which is inherited from Brush

```
#region Assembly System.Windows.dll, v2.0.50727
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace System.Windows.Media
{
    // Summary:
    //     Paints an area with a solid color.
    [ContentProperty("Color", true)]
    public sealed class SolidColorBrush : Brush
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Identifies the System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.Color dependency property.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The identifier for the System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.Color dependency
        //     property.
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;

        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush class
        //     with no color.
        public SolidColorBrush();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush class
        //     with the specified System.Windows.Media.Color.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   color:
        //     The color to apply to the brush.
        public SolidColorBrush(Color color);

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the color of this System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The brush's color. The default value is System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent.
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So to achieve what you are looking for , you will have to use SolidColorBrush like below :

```
logUser.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```